# Error al ejecutar APP Android Studio "TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry"

Tags: android, android-studio

Al intentar ejecutar mi APP con Android studio, me sale este error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceReport.class
```

Lo he mirado por mil sitios y dicen como que algo esta duplicado, pero ya no sé que hacer ya, he hecho clean/rebuild, invalidate/cache ¿alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dam.proyectocristian"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Buenas Cristian, si puedes, te recomiendo que edites tu mensaje y pegues la parte del código más relevante para que entre todos podamos analizar bien el problema que expones.

Comment: He puesto donde creo que esta el error, ya que dice en el SO que hay algo duplicado pero no termino de entender lo que dicen en ingles

Comment: Creo que lo he solucionado cambiando la version de service maps y location a 9.2.1 igual que la de firebase-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase `java.util.zip.ZipException` esta duplicada,  en las dependencias:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
```

puedes agregar el bloque de configuración para que solo tengas la clase de una dependencia:

```
    android{
   ...    
   ...
   ...        
        configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
            all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }

    }
```

Revisa la sección configuración de dependencias.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html