# Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser xmlpull:xmlpull

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Mi proyecto Android ha dejado de compilar, realicé algunos cambios en la configuración y ahora me aparece el siguiente mensaje al tratar de compilar:

```
Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser found in modules kxml2-2.3.0.jar (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0) and xmlpull-1.1.3.4d_b4_min.jar (xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.4d_b4_min)
Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException found in modules kxml2-2.3.0.jar (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0) and xmlpull-1.1.3.4d_b4_min.jar (xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.4d_b4_min)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Pero no encuentro la documentación sobre este error.

Y no consigo descubrir qué librería genera el problema. A pesar de que he usado el analizador de dependencias no consigo tirar del hilo para descubrir la librería problemática ni el modo de solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si modificaste tu código probablemente sea un caso de clases repetidas,

[Error al ejecutar APP Android Studio "TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59441/error-al-ejecutar-app-android-studio)

En este caso define dentro de tu archivo `app/build.gradle` una exclusión de clases:

```
 android{
   ...    
   ...
   ...        
        configurations {
            all*.exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'             
        }

    }
```

El motivo de este problema que indica clases duplicadas, son las dependencias que definimos dentro de

```
dependencies {
               ...
               ...
             }
```

en ocasiones al definir libraries, estas hacen uso de clases que ya se encuentran en otra dependencia.

---

Pero si indicas que funcionaba tu proyecto y dejo de funcionar en una actualización de Android Studio, en este caso no indica un problema real de clases repetidas
En este caso te sugiero realizar la eliminación del caché mediante:

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Elena. Aunque lamentablemente no ha funcionado. Sigo igual... ;-(

Comment: @DanielInfante funcionaba antes de la actualización, o no era así?

Comment: Hola @elenasys! Antes de la actualización (y de algunos cambios en el código)... Las dos cosas han ocurrido a la vez. Creo que las clases están duplicadas de verdad y que hay que hacer caso al mensaje y ver por qué las clases están duplicadas. Quizás mi mensaje inicial es un poco confuso... Voy a cambiarlo

Comment: @DanielInfante bueno entonces si realizaste modificaciones y no funcionó la invalidación de caché es que en realidad existen clases repetidas debido a la configuración de dependencias, modifico mi respuesta.

Comment: Ante todo... Muchas gracias por tus respuestas @Elenasys. Lo curioso es que yo no he añadido esta librería a través de Gradle. Así que entiendo que una de las librerías que añado, tiene dependencia a su vez de kxml2 y otra de las que añado depende de xmlpull. ¿Sabes si hay manera de ver este gráfico de dependencias para saber qué librería es la culpable de que se cargue un módulo en particular?

Answer (score 0):

El problema fue solucionado añadiendo lo siguiente a build.gradle del módulo app:

```
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
}
```

Aún y así, me gustaría saber el motivo del error... Aunque lo he solucionado, no me acaba de convencer.

Comment: agrego el motivo en mi respuesta.