# Error en ejecutar mi aplicacion-Entrada duplicada

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un proyecto de Android y uso varios servicios de google, API facebook, y usando `firebase`. pero cuando la ejecuto me sale un error de duplicación y no entiendo el error

> Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential found in
>   modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-common:9.0.2)
>   and classes.ar (com.google.firebase:firebase-*auth:17.0.0)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Compañero el código va en forma de texto, como imagen no es muy apreciable.

Comment: Acostubra agregar como texto el build.gradle y el error por favor Andres, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes clases repetidas de Firebase debido a las dependencias que definiste en tu build.gradle, es un problema similar a :

[Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser xmlpull:xmlpull](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/278250/duplicate-class-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparser-xmlpullxmlpull/278380#278380)

Agrega dentro del bloque `configurations` de tu `build.gradle` lo siquiente:

```
 android{
   ...

        configurations {
            exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-auth'             
        }

    }
```